# Proof that the scalar curvature of a two-dimensional space can be expressed by only one component of the Riemann tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

So I'm working on a question that asks for a proof that in two-dimensional space, the scalar curvature is given by:

$$R = \frac{2R^1{}_{212}}{{g}_{22}}$$

Now, I've been playing around with the symetries of the Riemann tensor, and got $R$ into the following form:

$$R = {2{g}^{22}}{R^1{}_{212}}$$

Obviously, I need to convert between the metric tensor and the inverse metric tensor. However, the determinant seems to complicate matters... so I'm wondering if I can make the following two assumptions:

1. The metric is necessarily symmetric i.e. ${g}^{12}= {g}^{21}$
2. Any symmetric metric is diagonalizable, and so there exists some coordinate system where ${g}^{12}=0$

If the above two points are correct, then I can always write the metric in a coordinate system where it is diagonalized, and therefore can let ${g}^{22}=({g}_{22})^{-1}$.

This would then give the required formula above, and since the scalar curvature is a global property, then if it takes a particular value in one coordinate system, it must thereby take the same value in any other coordinate system.

So, are assumptions 1 and 2 correct?

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use that tag on this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the assumptions seem correct. The metric can be proven to be always symmetric by its definition. 
$$g_{ij} = \vec{e}_i \otimes \vec{e}_j$$
and
$$ds^2 = g_{ij}dx^{i}dx^{j}$$
The second assumption is true from the definition of tensors. *Tensors have the same magnitude in every frame of reference.*

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make that assumption. In two dimensions, we have
$$
R^a{}_{bcd} = \frac{R}{2} ( \delta^a_c g_{bd} - \delta^a_d g_{bc} ) 
$$
Then,
$$
R^1{}_{212} = \frac{R}{2} g_{22} \quad \implies \quad R = \frac{2}{g_{22} } R^1{}_{212}.
$$
I am not sure how you got the specific form you mention. We have
$$
R = g^{bd} g^{ac} R_{abcd}    = 2 (g^{11}g^{22} -  g^{12}  g^{21} ) R_{1212} = \frac{2}{ \det g } R_{1212}  
$$
Now, multiply both sides by $g^{11}$ so that
$$
R g^{11} \det g = 2 g^{11} R_{1212} = 2 R^1{}_{212}
$$
Finally, $g^{11} \det g = g_{22}$ so that
$$
R g_{22} = 2 R^1{}_{212} \quad \implies \quad R = \frac{2}{g_{22}} R^1{}_{212}. 
$$